# header position of the grid not fixed while printing,

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is a grid that populates data,

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="1000px" 
  Height="8000px" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" Visible="true" BackColor="LightGray">
<asp:GridView ID="List" runat="server" Visible="False" OnRowDataBound="List_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

      <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridstyleHead" />
      <RowStyle CssClass="gridRowstyle" />

</asp:GridView>
```

and there is a style sheet that applies to grid

```
.gridstyleHead {
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: left;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: lighter;
padding-left: 3px;
position: relative;
top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
z-index: 10;
}

.gridRowstyle {
white-space: nowrap;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: white;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 9pt;
height: 29px;
```

}

i am trying to print the data that is in grid

```
function btnPrint_Click() {
varfoo="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,
width=500,height=600,left=50,top=25";


  varprintdata=document.getElementById('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
        var printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', foo);
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("ordrcvd");
        var ord = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
            if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
                ord = radioButtons[x].value;
            }
        }
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/invoice.css" />');
        printWindow.document.write(' </head><body>');
        printWindow.document.write('<table>');
        printWindow.document.write('<tr><td style = "font-weight:bold;font-family:arial;font-size:12"> order Received' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  : ');
        printWindow.document.write('</td><td style = "font-weight:normal;font-family:arial;font-size:12">');
        printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('<%= txtordRcvd.ClientID%>').value);
        printWindow.document.write('</td></tr>');
        printWindow.document.write('<tr><td> </br>');
        printWindow.document.write('</td></tr>');
        printWindow.document.write(' </table>');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();

        return false;
    }
```

but the problem is header in the grid is not fixed and 
the one am printing is showing the grid with header not fixed.

Header in the grid being not fixed is fine but when am trying to print that grid and scroll down, the header position is misplaced.

can anyone suggest how to apply stylesheet for the grid that am printing, so that header will be fixed

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the print media query.  I can't test it to be sure, but I believe you want something like this:

```
@media print { 
    .gridstyleHead {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Or whatever number gets your header to be in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I tried this way and it worked for me,
Before(mentioned as in question) there was a panel called panel1 and data was binded to the grid in that panel and style sheet was applied to that grid which says the header to be fixed.
Now, I took another panel similar to Panel1 and named it Panel2 but applied style so that it doesn't display and data was binded to the grid in that panel2, similar to before process and style sheet was applied to that grid which says the header to be "Not Fixed". Hope am not bad at explanation.

Steps that I followed:

I included a class to the existing css file removing the expression "top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);" from gridstyleHead

```
.gridstyleHeadlocal
{
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: left;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: lighter;
padding-left: 3px;
position: relative;

z-index: 10;
}
```

and  now i took another Panel2 which acts like Panel1 as am applying style  for it with style = Display:none

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" style = "Display:none" runat="server" 
ScrollBars="Auto" Width="1000px" 
         Height="8000px" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" 
        Visible="true" 
       BackColor="LightGray">
       <asp:GridView ID="Listlocal" runat="server" Visible="False" 
        OnRowDataBound="List_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridstyleHeadlocal" />
       <RowStyle CssClass="gridRowstyle" />

 </asp:GridView>
```

and called Panel2 in  Print button function using 
    document.getElementById('<%=Panel2.ClientID%>').innerHTML;

```
  function btnPrint_Click() {
 varfoo="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=600,left=50,top=25";


  varprintdata=document.getElementById('<%=Panel2.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', foo);
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("ordrcvd");
    var ord = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
        if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
            ord = radioButtons[x].value;
        }
    }
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/invoice.css" />');
    printWindow.document.write(' </head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write('<table>');
    printWindow.document.write('<tr><td style = "font-weight:bold;font-family:arial;font-size:12"> order Received' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  : ');
    printWindow.document.write('</td><td style = "font-weight:normal;font-family:arial;font-size:12">');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('<%= txtordRcvd.ClientID%>').value);
    printWindow.document.write('</td></tr>');
    printWindow.document.write('<tr><td> </br>');
    printWindow.document.write('</td></tr>');
    printWindow.document.write(' </table>');
    printWindow.document.write(printContent);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();

    return false;
   }
```